# Convert/distort image to match Mercator projection

Tags: php, image, dictionary, overlay, mercator

I have an image, which is basically just a screenshot from Google Maps. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iufcw.jpg)

And I have another image, which I would like to display over my map.

I know the coordinates (lat/lon) of all four corners of my map, and they match the four corners of my overlay image.

**My problem:** The map is in Mercator projection (which means the scale increases from the Equator to the pole), while my overlay image is not. Therefor my overlay image is accurate at the top and bottom of my map, but a bit off at the centre.

**My question:** How can I convert/distort my overlay image so that it will match the Mercator projection of my map? I'm hoping to be able to this in **PHP**.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's how I overlay generated images onto a Google or Bing map.
In my case, I'm creating a GD image of polygons that will be the overlay.  It's much faster to do the polygons in the GD library than the map providers APIs.

First, set up scaling from a standard latitude longitude to a WGS84 projection.  Degrees to mercator x-y coordinates in meters.

http://gisgeography.com/wgs84-world-geodetic-system/

//      $minlat = minimum image latitude

//      $minlon = minimum image longitude

//      $maxlat = maximum image latitude

//      $maxlon = maximum image longitude

//      $latbounds = Image height (in pixels)

//      $lonbounds = Image width (in pixels)

```
$lonrange = abs($maxlon - $minlon);

$WGS84min = log(tan((90.+$minlat)*M_PI/360.))/(M_PI/180.);
$WGS84min = (int) ($WGS84min * 2037598.34/180);
$WGS84max = log(tan((90.+$maxlat)*M_PI/360.))/(M_PI/180.);
$WGS84max = (int) ($WGS84max * 2037598.34/180);
$WGS84diff = $WGS84max - $WGS84min;
$WGS84factor = $latbounds/$WGS84diff;
```

Then for each latitude/longitude I want to calculate the actual X-Y coordinates on the image.

// $lon1 = the longitude of the point to be converted into image coordinates

// $lat1 = the latitude of the point to be converted into image coordates

X is easy

```
$x = (int) ((abs($lon1-$minlon)/$lonrange)*$lonbounds);
```

Y is a bit harder, first calculating to WGS84, and then mapping to the image.  Last step, inverting the Y coordinates since the display order is upside down.

```
$y1 = log(tan((90.+$lat1)*M_PI/360.))/(M_PI/180.);
$y1 = $y1 * 2037598.34/180;
$y1 = (int) (($y1- $WGS84min)*$WGS84factor);
$y  = $latbounds - $y1;
```

when the image file is complete, use GD to save the image and then use the example in the API library to display your overlay.

In your case, this could be rather slow because you have to calculate the lat / lon of each image pixel coordinate and then map the pixel value into the new image at the new coordinate.  However in that case you wouldn't have to flip the Y at the end of each calculation, but you might see some strange aliasing where two pixels mapped to the same coordinate, and another pixel never got a data value.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple