# Get latitude/longitude of an image's corners

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math, leaflet, mercator

I have an image that represents a region on the map. For example, this image is 10000px wide by 8000px high. I don't know what the area of this region represented in the image is in terms of m².

What I can do is select a point in the image (x, y) and match that point on the map to get the latitude, longitude. I can do this with almost all points/pixels in the image except those on the edge (imagine that the image has a wide border that is just a white space, and I cannot relate these points within the map to obtain the latitude/longitude).

My goal is to add this image inside the map in a way that it fits perfectly on the map. For this I have to use [Leaflet's ImageOverlay feature](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay). However, to use this feature, I need to specify the image's bounds. In other words, I would need the latitude/longitude of two specific points in the image: **bottom left and top right**.

The first thing I tried was to obtain the equation of the line. As I have the relationship of two other points, I can draw the equation of the latitude/longitude line for this map and then obtain the latitude of every x/y. But as you can already imagine, since the map isn't a "2d plane", the straight line equation appears to be inefficient here.

In pixels, these points would be respectively (0px, 8000px) and (10000px, 0px). Unfortunately these are points that I cannot relate manually due to the mentioned border problem. **Is there some kind of calculation I can do to get the latitude/longitude of these fields?**

I've tried several alternatives, but all without success. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem.

**UPDATES:**

What I want is different from "[Convert X,Y pixel to Longitude and Latitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954628/convert-x-y-pixel-to-longitude-and-latitude)" because in this example the user has precisely the latitudes/longitudes of the corners (max/min lat/long). **Which is exactly what I need**.

What I want is different from "[Convert/distort image to match Mercator projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830382/convert-distort-image-to-match-mercator-projection)" because again the user knows the coordinates of all corners of the image. **Which is exactly what I need**.

I don't think it's necessary to share the code because I believe the problem is one of mathematics and not programming. What I can do is share the variables I have:

Image width: 15767px
Image height: 10629px

This image represents a region on the map, just like [this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iufcw.jpg).

I can relate some points more in the center of the image, such as:

```
var points = {
    a: {
        lat: -23.189714427995956,
        long: -45.95251764954021,
        x: 5896,
        y: 2908
    },
    b: {
        lat: -23.19225387170598,
        long: -45.95226547201594,
        x: 6123,
        y: 5432
    }
};
```

With these variables I need a function that returns the latitude/longitude of any point (x, y) within the image. Of course, my interest is not to obtain the latitude/longitude of ALL points. The points that really interest me are those necessary to obtain the image's bounds and then be able to use the ImageOverlay feature correctly.

**The points are bottom left (0, 10629) and top right (15767, 0).**

Comment: *imagine* is like a forbidden word here in SO, you have to share actual code, create a snippet with your code [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Share what have you tried, where are you stuck? any error messages? and we can help you from there

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830382/convert-distort-image-to-match-mercator-projection

Comment: I updated the question text. The answers mentioned do not work in my case.